# convert date from one format to another format

Tags: objective-c

HI all,

i have a date string like this

```
2011-03-31 13:32:02
```

i want to convert this date string to display like this

```
Thursday – March 31, 2011
```

Please help to solve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter. First initialize the formatter with the [appropriate format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) to parse the source string, something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Then use it to parse the date string:

```
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:string];
```

Now you can create a new formatter to output in the new format, or just reuse the existing one:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE - MMMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *output = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```